# Apple hardware diagnostics freezes at 95%

Tags: macos, hard-drive, boot, memory

Recently my Mid-2011 iMac (default specs except 2x 4GB RAM boards were added years ago, running latest OS X and most recently updated days ago) has been locking up during use - a single random app would get a beach-ball - sometimes it would finally clear, and sometimes the system would lock-up hard - the dock, the hard drive icons, some finder toolbar icons, etc would vanish, the mouse wouldn't move and keyboard won't work so I have no choice but a hard reboot. iTunes would halt playback as if there was an issue accessing the disk or ram.

I booted into single-user mode, ran `fsck -fy` and it repaired some minor errors but the problem continued.

I booted into the apple hardware diagnostic software and at first, it was reporting `4MEM` errors. The plan was to remove RAM boards one-by-one to determine which was corrupt. The test passed after I re-seated both original 2GB boards, which is odd given that they haven't moved since I bought the machine and nothing's happened that would have jolted it.

However, even though the diagnostics test passes the memory section, it freezes around 95%, the mouse becomes choppy/jumpy, and the only way to shut it down is to hard-reset.

I tried to let the machine boot normally just to see what would happen and now it auto-shuts off half-way through the boot sequence.

Is there anything else I can do to narrow down the cause? I have a time machine backup of all my files but would much rather avoid buying a whole new machine or taking it to a repair shop and wasting a several hundred.

Comment: Could you clarify "However, even though the diagnostics test passes the memory section, it freezes around 95%, the mouse becomes choppy/jumpy, and the only way to shut it down is to hard-reset." How can it pass the test if you have to hard reset?

Comment: The memory test is one in a series - memory, logic board, etc. It's unclear which phase it's testing when it freezes. Anyway I've taken it to apple for more thorough diagnostics and they confirmed it's the hard drive failing physically.